# make QTableView column read-only using Python

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview

I have searched the archives and I found the following code:

```
class ManifestModel: public QSqlTableModel
{
public: 
    ManifestModel(QObject * parent = 0, QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase() ):
        QSqlTableModel(parent, db)
    { }
    ~ManifestModel() { }
    Qt::ItemFlags flags ( const QModelIndex & index ) const 
    {
        if (index.column() == 2)
            return Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
        else
            return Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
    }
};
```

Then use ManifestModel in place of QSqlTableModel.

This does exactly what I need to do, but I don't understand C++ syntax. Could someone please convert this to Python for me. I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what works in PyQt5:

class ManifestModel(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):

```
def __init__(self, parent=None, db=QtSql.QSqlDatabase()):
    super(ManifestModel, self).__init__(parent, db)

def flags(self, index):
    if (index.column() == 4):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
    elif (index.column() == 6):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled  
    else:
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work but I didn't test it:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt4.QtSql import QSqlTableModel, QSqlDatabase


class ManifestModel(QSqlTableModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, db=QSqlDatabase()):
        super(ManifestModel, self).__init__(parent, db)

    def flags(self, index):
        if (index.column() == 2):
            return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable
        else:
            return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable
```

The `__init__` method is the equivalent of the C++ constructor `ManifestModel()`. `super` calls the parent constructor, here `QSqlTableModel`. You should always follow this pattern when subclassing.

The method `~ManifestModel()` is a destructor, you usually don't need to worry about it in python, there's no need to define a method.

`flags` is a class method, the C++ syntax

```
TypeOfOutput functionName( typeOfParameter1 parameter1){}
```

has a simpler equivalent in python:

```
functionName(self, parameter1):
```

Finally, the C++ `Qt::` becomes `Qt.` or `QtCore.Qt.`, depending on the imports.

Comment: My advice is try to get use to the C++ syntax, the Qt doc in C++ is way better than the PyQt doc (it's easier to read and browse in my opinion).

Comment: That looks like it should work. I will test it when I go in to work next week. Apparently I am not supposed to thank you? I agree about c++ syntax but I don't see how I can do it without learning to program c++, which I don't want to do.

Comment: I am trying to use the code that you gave me but I am getting an error.

Comment: builtins.TypeError: flags() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: I fixed the flags() error by adding "def flags(self, index):" but now I get "builtins.NameError: name 'Qt' is not defined"  The documentation states 'This enum describes the properties of an item:' and I do not see where the 'item' is or why index has a column attribute. If you like, I can send you my code but I can't do it in a comment.

Comment: I got it to work. The pyqt5 code is:                                           class ManifestModel(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):

 def __init__(self, parent=None, db=QtSql.QSqlDatabase()):
  super(ManifestModel, self).__init__(parent, db)

 def flags(self, index):
  if (index.column() == 4):
   return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
  else:
   return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable

Comment: I was sure I would forget something.. Of course every class method in python need a first argument `self` , that you don't have in C++. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but since I struggled a bit, here is an extended solution for a `QStandardItemModel`. one can choose which columns to set read only passing a list of them to `MyStandardItemModel.setReadOnly`

```
class MyStandardItemModel(QStandardItemModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, *arg, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *arg, **kwargs)
        self.__readonly_cols = []

    def flags(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex) -> QtCore.Qt.ItemFlags:
            if (index.column() in self.__readonly_cols):
                return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
            else:
                return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def setReadOnly(self, columns: [int]):
        for i in columns:
            if i <= (self.columnCount() - 1) and i not in self.__readonly_cols:
                self.__readonly_cols.append(i)

    def resetReadOnly(self):
        self.__readonly_cols = []
```

Hope it can be of use to others